# BootstrapValidator form submit not working

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, jqbootstrapvalidation

I have a form with 2 buttons. One button submits the form in ajax format and another button submits the form in normal fashion.

```
$('#form_createAd').bootstrapValidator({
    submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
        if (submitButton.attr('value') == "cart"){
            submit_cartDetails(); //This function submits details thru ajax post
        } else {
            form.submit(); // Also Tried $('#form_createAd').submit()
        }
    }, fields: {
        title: {
            message: 'The username is not valid',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The username is required and can\'t be empty'
                },
                stringLength: {
                    min: 6,
                    max: 30,
                    message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                },
                regexp: {
                    regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                    message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This Is The HTML Part Of Buttons Inside  Form Section

```
<button  id="cart" value="cart" class="btn btn-primary" >Add To Cart</button>             
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="proceed" class="btn btn-success">Proceed</button>
```

The form doesn't submit. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please be more mindful when tagging your question.  [tag:jquery-validate] plugin is not the same as the Bootstrap Validator plugin.

Comment: I've facing same problem with it. Using BootstrapValidator 0.5.1

Answer (score 26):

I'm the creator of BootstrapValidator plugin.

The issue is caused by using `submit` to name the submit button. Changing `name="submit"` to something else will fix the issue.

- [Getting Started](https://formvalidation.io/guide/getting-started/)
- [Warning](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/getting-started/#name-conflict)

Comment: Been trying to use the submitHandler but it never enters the function when i click on the buttons.

Comment: Saved my time. Thanks

Comment: I spent ages trying to work this out before seeing this. Thanks too much!!

Answer (score 0):

It could be a handful of things:

- form id matches both html and js
- submitHandler is actually working?
- is the library even loaded?

That's just at the top of my head. A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) might help.